# how to set width to be number of characters?

Tags: flutter, textfield

Flutter TextField: how to set width to be number of characters?

Equivalent to HTML:

```
 <input type='text' size='20' />
```

Answer (score 1):

create a TextField widget and set its width to be based on the number of characters by using the maxLines and maxLength properties along with a TextEditingController.

Example:

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
@override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int desiredLength = 20; // your desired length
    int currentLength = _controller.text.length;
    int remainingLength = desiredLength - currentLength;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child:
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              maxLength: desiredLength,
              maxLines: 1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter text'),
           ),
        );
     }
```

now you can access current and remaining length from

> currentLength remainingLength variables

Comment: The max length is different from size, right?

Comment: yes maxLength is how many numbers of characters a textField could have

Comment: need to set size (visible length) though.

Comment: sorry for late reply! 
you can wrap your TextField inside SizedBox widget, then give width as you want